# Bootstrap modal, show after completion of something

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I successfully created a modal using bootstrap. But so far I was only able to show this modal when clicking a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>
```

How can I show this modal after completion of something? Or in other words: How can I trigger this modal in code?

Answer (score 1):

Simply trigger click handler for that button:

```
$('[data-target="#myModal"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: But I don't want to use any button. This modal should show without button. How do I implement this directly in HTML?

Comment: You must use button to target. But you may hide it using simple css `display:none;`

Comment: Ah ok thx. And how or where do I implement your code? To clarify I am using shiny to create a web interface. After some code is run I want to trigger this.

Comment: Before closing the body inside script.